# c sizeof function of an array in a function is always four bytes despite the number of array elements

Tags: arrays, function-pointers, sizeof

When I print the (size of the array/size of the the first element), I get the right answer, but when I do the same thing in the function, I get the size of the array to be four and the size of the first element of the array to be four hence the division is always one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int sizer(int *); 

int main()
{
    int num;
    printf("Please an index: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    int array[num];
    int size = sizer(array); //function to calculate array length

    /*answer is always 4*/
    printf("%d\n", size); 

    /*answer is correct*/
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])); 

    return 0;
}

/*function to calculate array length*/
int sizer(int *array)
{
    return sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

Comment: The short answer: you can't pass arrays to functions, only pointers to their first element. Thus, the sizeof of any function's pointer parameter is always the size of the pointer.

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically allocate that array? Since `num` does not have a value known at compile time, this looks like bad code to me. Lookup dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @user3728501 It's allowed in C99. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Fair enough - how does that work in terms of machine code? I assume there must be some sort of loop which does a "push" operation on the stack until the size required is reserved on the stack?

Comment: @user3728501 Just move the stack pointer `sizeof(T)*len` bytes up and use the resulting space as the array.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is not a function called at runtime, even though it looks like one.  It is a feature of the compiler.  It looks at a data object and replaces the `sizeof()` expression with a constant.

```
int arr[10];
int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
```

This works because the compielr can see how big `arr` is.  `arr` is a statically sized array here.  Both `sizeof` expressions are replaced with the appropriate values.

```
int arr[10];
int size = sizer(arr);
....
int sizer(int array[]) {
    return (sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));
}
```

This doesn't work.  In `sizer`, `array` looks like an array but arrays passed in as parameters are actually just pointers to the array type.  So `sizeof(array)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int *)`

```
scanf("%d",&num);
int arr[num];
int size1 = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
int size2 = sizer(arr);
....
int sizer(int array[]) {
    return (sizeof(array)/sizeof(int));
}
```

Here, `size1` works but `size2` doesn't.  The creation of `arr` is actually allocated like this:

```
int arr_sizeof = sizeof(int)*num;
int *arr = alloca(arr_sizeof);
```

Then later on, `sizeof(arr)` is quietly replaced with `arr_sizeof`.  But the compiler can only do this in the same scope that `arr` is created, because when `arr` is passed to `sizer` it's just converted to an `int *` again, so the size information is not carried over.  `sizer` fails for thet same reason, arrays in function parameters are just passed along as simple pointers.

Comment: You can pass the length of the array in arguments as well, e.g. (`size_t size(size_t len, int a[len])`, but the type in the function is still `int*`.  So `sizeof` would still only return the size of the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array to a function you are really just passing a pointer to the first element, so in the body of `sizer`, the parameter `array` is just a pointer to `int`. Your function correctly returns `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)` (which is 2 rather than 4 on my machine), though this is probably not what you want. There really isn't any way for a function in C to compute the length of a passed array, which is why it is standard in C to pass the number of elements in an array as one of the parameters in any function which takes an array parameter.